# Importing multiple GeoTiffs in TileMill

Tags: tilemill, gdalwarp, mbtiles, gdalbuildvrt, geotiff-tiff

I am a software engineer that is very new in the geo world. So excuse my ignorance if this question seems simple or if terms I use are totally wrong.

**Problem:**

I have been tasked with taking multiple geotiffs and serving them from a map tile system on our servers. From my research so far, I believe that I need to convert these geotiffs to mbtiles. I've got the serving of the mbtiles part figured out, what I really need help on is coming up with a quick way to convert the geotiffs into mbtiles.

**Things I've tried:**

I currently have a script that can do this conversion of 56GB of Geotiffs in about 7.25 hours using gdalbuildvrt, gdalwarp, and gdal2tiles. Here is what it does:

```
ls -1 *.tiff > files.txt
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list files.txt project.vrt
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -of VRT project.vrt project_mercator.vrt
gdal2tiles.py project_mercator.vrt project.mbtiles
```

It works but I'd like to improve on this.

I've heard that it might be faster to use TileMill to export, but so far my attempts to import the geotiffs into TileMill have failed. I have 158 geotiffs and I don't want to have to "Add Layer" for each one using the interface.

I thought I might be able to import the .vrt file I generated in my own script but when I try to add it in TileMill I get an error that says, "GDALWarpOptions.Validate() hSrsDS is not set".

**Question to the community:**

What is the best way to import multiple geotiffs into a TileMill project?

Comment: Maybe GeoServer would be an option too: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/index.html - and I only suggest wondering what clients of MBTiles you're thinking about?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?